# D3 .classed() Using multiple selectors (Version 4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using version 4 of D3 and trying to select the third item, remove the item class, and add the highlight and bigger classes. For some reason the item class is not being removed. And suggestions?

HTML Code

```
  <div class="container">
      <h2>D3 Graphic</h2>
      <section id="chart">
           <div class="item">Barot Bellingham</div>
           <div class="item">Hassum Harrod</div>
           <div class="item">Jennifer Jerome</div>
           <div class="item">Richard Tweet</div>
           <div class="item">Lorenzo Garcia</div>
           <div class="item">Xhou Ta</div>
      </section>
 </div>
```

D3 Code

```
d3.selectAll('.item:nth-child(3)')
.classed(
    'highlight', true,
    'item', false,
    'bigger', true
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT : for v4. You can write a function but, it is simpler this way.

```js
d3.selectAll('.item:nth-child(3)')
    .classed('highlight bigger',true)
    .classed('item',false);
```

```css
 .highlight {
    color : red;
    }
    .item {
    font-weight : bold;
    }
    .bigger {
    font-size : 24px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
          <h2>D3 Graphic</h2>
          <section id="chart">
               <div class="highlight">Barot Bellingham</div>
               <div class="item">Hassum Harrod</div>
               <div class="item">Jennifer Jerome</div>
               <div class="item">Richard Tweet</div>
               <div class="item">Lorenzo Garcia</div>
               <div class="bigger">Xhou Ta</div>
          </section>
     </div>
```

Original answer : Your syntax is wrong.

```js
d3.selectAll('.item:nth-child(3)')
.classed({
    'highlight': true,
    'item': false,
    'bigger': true
});
```

```css
.highlight {
color : red;
}
.item {
font-weight : bold;
}
.bigger {
font-size : 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <h2>D3 Graphic</h2>
      <section id="chart">
           <div class="highlight">Barot Bellingham</div>
           <div class="item">Hassum Harrod</div>
           <div class="item">Jennifer Jerome</div>
           <div class="item">Richard Tweet</div>
           <div class="item">Lorenzo Garcia</div>
           <div class="bigger">Xhou Ta</div>
      </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is D3 version 3.x. The OP is talking about v4.

Comment: Yeah I was just about to mention this syntax is v3. Any ideas on how to get it to work in v4?

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for - thanks so much! It makes a lot more sense now looking at how the syntax works. :)